# Outlook displays persistent unknown error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, windows-error-reporting

Whenever I start MS Outlook 2003, I get the well known Microsoft's pop up window displaying:

"Microsoft Office Outlook has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Send Error Report   |  Don't Send "

Then, the program closes. Everytime. I've never encountered anything like that before, so please any help??

Answer (score 1):

The following steps may help:

1. Use the *Inbox Repair Tool* `scanpst`  to check if your `.OST` (online inbox) and `.PST` (offline personal storage) files are consistent. The tool offers to repair damages found.
   See [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/usingscanpst.htm), how to do it.
2. Start Outlook in save mode using the `/save` switch
   See [here](http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/start-outlook-in-safe-mode/), how to do it
3. Switch off all outlook add-ins
   See [here](http://blog.techhit.com/5527-how-to-find-and-disable-outlook-2003-add-ins-and-plugins), how to do it
   You can then re-activate them one-by-one to see, which one caused the problem.
4. Make use of the Office Repair Feature
   See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822238/en-us), how to do it
5. Upgrade to Outlook 2013
   Support for Outlook 2003 ended in April 2014.

Additionally, you might want to have a look at your [Windows Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to uncover possible problems with your system.

As @sunk818 is suggesting in his comment, you might have general problems with your Windows (XP?) or your file system. Are there any other Windows Event messages which are pointing in this direction?

Good luck!

Comment: The first step proposed by @Axel above, was done succesfully. However, when starting Outlook in safe mode the same thing keeps happening which forces the application to close. I see multiple errors caused by outlook.exe in Event Viewer, which display the following description of the problem: Faulting application outlook.exe, version 11.0.6565.0, stamp 42cacc7d, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.6532, stamp 53203b92, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000a93e. Are these somehow useful to handle the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue. Google might show something if you enter fault address and/or error ID. Try step 3.

Comment: 1) Did you try a sfc /scannow? 
2) You also try a full uninstall of Office, then redo the install.

Answer (score 0):

We got the exact same error & fault address. Turned out for us that there were corrupted emails sitting on the POP3 server. Once they were cleared out by logging into webmail, the problem stopped.